# Комплиция OpenCV в го

Tags: golang, opencv

Устанавливаю по данному [мануалу](https://gocv.io/getting-started/windows/). Но в итоге выходит данная ошибка при компиляции.

```
C:\opencv\opencv- 
3.4.3\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:1309:1: error: 
prototype for 'google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parser::Parser(bool)' 
doesnot 
match any in class 'google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parser'
TextFormat::Parser::Parser(bool allow_unknown_field)
                           ^
In file included from C:\opencv\opencv- 
3.4.3\3rdparty\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\text_format.cc:43:0:
C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/include/google/protobuf/text_format.h:458:
28:error: candidates are: constexpr 
google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parser::Parser(const 
google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parser&)
class LIBPROTOBUF_EXPORT Parser {
                        ^
C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/Library/include/google/protobuf/
text_format.h:460:
5:   error:                 google::protobuf::TextFormat::Parser::Parser()
  Parser();
  ^
 3rdparty\protobuf\CMakeFiles\libprotobuf.dir\build.make:762: recipe for 
 target 
'3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/
text_format.cc.obj' failed mingw32-make[2]: *** 
[3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/src/google/protobuf/
text_format.cc.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:650: recipe for target 
'3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [3rdparty/protobuf/CMakeFiles/libprotobuf.dir/all] 
Error 
2
Makefile:161: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

ОС: Windwos 10, go version go1.11.1 windows/amd64

Comment: Виталий, добро пожаловать на СО. Здесь не особо приветствуются скриншоты. Лучше вставьте текст самой ошибки в вопрос.

Comment: @Ainar-G, удалил скриншот, вставил текст ошибки, надеюсь на помощь.

Comment: http://answers.opencv.org/question/196153/protobuf-build-error-opencv-342/

Answer (score 1):

У меня была подобная ошибка, я выключил антивирус и у меня все собралось. 
Дело в том, что антивирусы mingw не очень любят.